# no internet connection when in private network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, ipv4

I have an ubuntu server with a public IP, which I can reach with ssh from my local machine.
However, when i put this server in a private network, I can no longer reach it with ssh from my local machine. Also, this server no longer has internet connection. (pinging google returns "unknown host")

If I remove the server from the private network, I can ssh to it again.

Here is the output of ifconfig:

```
eth0  
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:0c:fa:58:e9:89  
      inet addr:83.212.x.x  Bcast:83.212.x.x  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: y::y:y:y:y/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:232 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:39445 (39.4 KB)  TX bytes:16357 (16.3 KB)

eth1  
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:0a:e5:59:7a  
      inet6 addr: y:y:y:y:y:y:y:y/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: y:y:y:y:y:y:y:y/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: y::y:y:y:y/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:70070 (70.0 KB)  TX bytes:255901 (255.9 KB)
eth2      
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:35:7a:43:a4:77  
      inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: y::y:y:y:y/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:117153 (117.1 KB)  TX bytes:24309 (24.3 KB)

lo      
Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:17715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:3986302 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3986302 (3.9 MB)
```

An here is the output of `netstat -nr`:

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0       0     eth2
0.0.0.0         83.212.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0       0     eth0
83.212.x.x      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0       0     eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0       0     eth2
```

I have tried NATing, but it didn't work. Maybe I didn't do something correctly. I have no access to the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0       0     eth2
0.0.0.0         83.212.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0       0     eth0
```

You've got two default routes, you should only have one.

You can delete the route using `route del default gw 192.168.0.1`. I'm not certain of the syntax for ubuntu so you may want to double-check the man page first.

On a redhat-based system, you could remove it permanently by deleting the `GATEWAY` line in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2`  and doing `ifcfg eth2 down; ifcfg eth2 up`. I don't have a ubuntu server handy to find the matching commands there.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and there are no such files. I believe the equivalent is /etc/network/interfaces, which has no information about eth2. It just has the following lines:  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  
  
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp  

Also, there is no command ifcfg

Comment: I don't have any ubuntu server handy to check the syntax. But I'll update my answer with another way to temporarily fix it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Just for future reference, after doing this, you should also execute (in Ubuntu at least): `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`